# ¿Por qué se cambian todas las llaves del diccionario intentando cambiar solo una?

Tags: python, clase, python-3.7, diccionarios

Tengo una función que hace un diccionario con *n* diccionarios con la misma estructura:

```
def modelvardic(self,x):
    self.modelvar = {}
    estructura ={
            "it" : 1,
            "cc" : 0.4,
            "ang1" : 0,
            "ang2" : 0,
            "ang3" : 0,
            "a_hmax" : 10,
            "a_hmin" : 5,
            "a_vert" : 10
            }

    for i in range(x):
        self.modelvar[i+1] = estructura
```

Hasta acá todo bien, el problema es cuando trato de cambiar un valor dentro del diccionario con la siguiente función:

```
def modmodelvars(self,index,caract,valor):
    
    if caract == 1 :
        self.modelvar[index].update(it = valor)
    elif caract == 2 : 
        self.modelvar[index].update(cc = valor)
    elif caract == 3 : 
        self.modelvar[index].update(ang1 = valor)
    elif caract == 4 : 
        self.modelvar[index].update(ang2 = valor)
    elif caract == 5 : 
        self.modelvar[index].update(ang3 = valor)
    elif caract == 6 : 
        self.modelvar[index].update(a_hmax = valor)
    elif caract == 7 : 
        self.modelvar[index].update(a_hmin = valor)
    elif caract == 8 : 
        self.modelvar[index].update(a_vert = valor)
```

Pasa que si tengo un diccionario con tres llaves, y quiero cambiar el valor de solo una de las llaves, se cambia en todas las llaves.

```
test1.modelvar
```

---

```
Out[42]: 
{1: {'it': 1,
  'cc': 100,
  'ang1': 0,
  'ang2': 0,
  'ang3': 0,
  'a_hmax': 10,
  'a_hmin': 5,
  'a_vert': 10},
 2: {'it': 1,
  'cc': 100,
  'ang1': 0,
  'ang2': 0,
  'ang3': 0,
  'a_hmax': 10,
  'a_hmin': 5,
  'a_vert': 10},
 3: {'it': 1,
  'cc': 100,
  'ang1': 0,
  'ang2': 0,
  'ang3': 0,
  'a_hmax': 10,
  'a_hmin': 5,
  'a_vert': 10}}
```

Ahí puse la siguiente instrucción:

```
test1.modmodelvars(1,2,100)
```

Se cambió en las tres llaves el valor de `cc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En python, el concepto de **variable** es algo diferente a otros lenguajes. Cuando en muchos lenguajes se trata de un espacio para almacenar valores en memoria, en python es una simple *referencia* a un objeto.

Si hacemos:

```py
a = {}
b = a
```

No estamos creando dos variables, sino dos referencias al mismo diccionario. Todo cambio que hagas con una las variables será visible por la otra.

Si a los elementos de `modelvar` asignas el mismo diccionario, `estructura`, todos los elementos estarán usando el mismo diccionario.

Para evitar este problema hay que crear nuevos diccionarios para cada elemento. Podemos hacerlo de varias formas:

### Pasando la creación del diccionario directamente al bucle:

En cada iteración se crea un nuevo diccionario, una nueva referencia:

```py
    for i in range(x):
        self.modelvar[i+1] = {
            "it" : 1,
            "cc" : 0.4,
            "ang1" : 0,
            "ang2" : 0,
            "ang3" : 0,
            "a_hmax" : 10,
            "a_hmin" : 5,
            "a_vert" : 10
            }
```

### Copiando el diccionario

Los diccionarios tienen un método para hacer copias de sí mismos:

```py
    for i in range(x):
        self.modelvar[i+1] = estructura.copy()
```

### Clonando el diccionario

Si el diccionario a copiar tuviera más complejidad como *autoreferencias* o referencias a otros objetos, un simple copiado no resolvería todos los problemas. Hay que hacer una *copia en profundidad* para que también se creen copias de estas referencias. Para ello se usa el `copy.deepcopy` que nos haría un clonaje recursivo completo:

```py
    import copy

    for i in range(x):
        self.modelvar[i+1] = copy.deepcopy(estructura)
```

Comment: Amplia tu respuesta para hablar sobre `matriz = [[0] * 8] * 8`

Comment: Creo que ya está suficientemente explicado. Siempre se pueden buscar [más preguntas](/questions/376329/duda-bucle-for-y-metodo-remove-de-listas/376341) o hacer nuevas.